# Kafka 0.8 producer, use of "request.required.acks" property

Tags: message-queue, apache-kafka

From [0.8 Documentation](http://kafka.apache.org/08/configuration.html) under  producer config
the property `request.required.acks`

> value controls when the `producer receives an acknowledgement` from the broker.
>
> Typical values are
>
> (1) 0, which means that the producer never waits for an acknowledgement from the broker
>
> (2) 1, which means that the `producer gets an acknowledgement` after the leader replica has received the data
>
> (3) -1, which means that the `producer gets an acknowledgement` after all in-sync replicas have received the data

How do I receive this acknowledgement in producer when the `request.required.acks` value is `1`. The `producer.send(MessageKey)` being a void I couldn't find any options to retrieve it.

Comment: Just guessing, but maybe an exception is thrown if sending didn't receive an acknowledgement?

Answer (score 0):

The API for the producer send leaves much to be desired, particularly in the async mode. Those acks are hidden from the user of the producer object. If they fail, you will eventually see an exception.

The problem in the async case is that you will not know were the batch that failed began, so some guessing will be involved if you want to retry the sends later.

It seems that there are plans to improve this in future releases (> 0.8.0).